# Existence of codes

Tags: coding-theory

I am looking at the following exercise:

[image]

At $(a)$ and $(b)$ I have supposed that there is such a code. Then the Hamming bound has to be satisfied, i.e.  $M \leq \frac{q^n}{\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor \frac{d-1}{2}\rfloor} \binom{n}{i}(q-1)^i} $ .But this leads to a contradiction.

For $(d)$ I have thought that it holds that $ 2^{57}=\frac{2^{63}}{\sum_{i=0}^1 \binom{63}{i}} $. But from this we cannot deduce that there is a perfect binary linear code with parameters $(63, 2^{57},3)$, right?

At $(c)$ and $(d)$ the Hamming bound is satisfied. From this we cannot deduce that such codes exist. How can we determine whether the stated codes exist or not?

Comment: I'm confused about the notation. What does the parameters tuple -say, $(8,29,3)$- mean?

Comment: It symbolizes an $(n,M,d)$ code where $n$ is the length , $M$ is the number of codewords and $d$ the minimum distance. @leonbloy

Comment: The binary code of length 24, minimum distance 8 and $2^{12}$ is difficult to come up with unless you have seen it. After studying the topic for a while, you recognize it right away, because it's [kinda famous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Golay_code). It is heavily connected to group theory, dense lattices and such.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ah I see. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, Hamming bound gives only a necessary condition for existence; if it's satisfied, we cannot deduce anything.

A bound that gives a sufficient condition is the [Gilbert–Varshamov bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Varshamov_bound).
You can try to apply it to problems c) and d)

Regarding e), recall that the Hamming codes are perfect codes. Check if the parameters given allow the construction of a Hamming code (they do).

Comment: I am looking at c) now. It holds that $\sum_{i=0}^{d-2} \binom{n-1}{i}(q-1)^i=64$. I wanted to calculate $q^{n-k}$. But how can we find $k$ ? In this case $M=q^k \Rightarrow 5=2^k$, but there is no such $k$. So what do we do in this case? Or am I doing something wrong? @leonbloy

Comment: @Evinda See that there is a bound for linear codes and other for arbitrary codes. In c) you are asked about a linear code. But, then, actually you don't need to use an bound. You cannot have a linear binary code with 5 codewords! If the code is linear, then $M=2^k$

Comment: Ah, I see. For $d$ I have found the following:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{d-2} \binom{n-1}{i} (q-1)^i=\sum_{i=0}^6 \binom{23}{i}=145499$$
Then $M=q^k \Rightarrow 2^{12}=2^k \Rightarrow k=12$.



So $q^{n-k}=2^{12}=4096$, so the Gilbert-Varshamov bound isn't satisfied. How else can we determine if such a code exists or not?

$$$$

As for $e$, the parameters of a binary Hamming code are $[2^r-1, 2^r-1-r, 3]$.

$$2^r-1=63 \Rightarrow r=6$$

For $r=6$, $2^r-1-r=57$, so there is a perfect binary linear code with parameters $(63, 2^{57},3)$, namely the binary Hamming code of length $63$.